# Create transcript of discord channel

Tags: discord, discord.py, ticket-system

Is it possible to create an archive of a channel using discord.py?
I have tried following this: [discrod.py Text channel history to HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844300/discrod-py-text-channel-history-to-html-file), however it:

1. Didn't send the file, no matter what I tried;
2. When I opened the file through the browser, it didn't create the style you see in ticket bots.

I am using discord-components, so therefore chat_exporter doesn't work due to a bug.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you checked [Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter/) ?

Comment: I added an answer using both methods in the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68923558/13975447)

Comment: @Abdulaziz Would Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter work since the bot is hosted externally, meaning I don't know the path to get to it

Comment: Download the `cli` version add it into the root folder for your repo. It should be in the folder called `DiscordChatExporter.CLI`

Comment: @Abdulaziz I tried that, but I now get this error: https://pastebin.com/sz0g7WL6

Comment: If you need the code, just say :-)

Comment: Yes please, it seems that the path given is a function not a `str`

Comment: @Abdulaziz It works now, made an error when copying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on [The original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844300/discrod-py-text-channel-history-to-html-file) is now working however, the answer by Bram does also work. With the solution on the original post, chat-exporter will not work alongside discord-components, though there may be a fix for the issue soon (either by discord-components updating, or discord.py 2.0 releasing)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
fileName = f"{ctx.channel.name}.txt"
with open(fileName, "w") as file:
    async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
        file.write(f"{msg.created_at} - 
                   {msg.author.display_name}: 
                   {msg.clean_content}\n")
```

If you want to send the file do:

```
file = discord.File(fileName)
await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Of course, you can send the file to wherever you want, but this is just an example.

Comment: Works, however isn’t like the transcript you see on bots like Ticket Tool, where there is a file that is like a screenshot of the channel

Comment: Well, that wasn't your question, I just gave you the answer on how to save a channel, and send it. I personally use this on my ticket system for my network. If you want to take screenshots, you need some sort of API to do that for you. I cannot help you with that. If it works I would highly appreciate it if you could upvote my answers, as it in fact did work.